# RegEx to replace spaces between numbers

Tags: javascript

I need to get rid of all the *spaces* between the individual time quotations *(hours: minutes: seconds,miliseconds)*.

This `string`

```
00: 00: 35,207 -> 00: 00: 38,664
```

Must become

```
00:00:35,207 -> 00:00:38,664
```

How can I do this using a `RegEx`?

I tried this

```js
var string = "00: 00: 35,207 -> 00: 00: 38,664";

console.log(string.replace(/(?<=\d+)\s+(?=\d+)/g, ""))
```

But that doens't work.

Comment: `str.replace(/: /g, ':')`?

Comment: @melpomene Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not support lookbehind `(?<=`

You could:

- Select what you want to replace, in this case the colon and the whitespace `:`
- Then replace that with a colon `:`

As @melpomene commented, you could use:

```js
var string = "00: 00: 35,207 -> 00: 00: 38,664";
console.log(string.replace(/: /g, ':'));
```

Use the `/g` global flag to not return after the first match.

If you want to use the positive lookahead you could use [`: (?=\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/aKOjOS/1)

```js
var string = "00: 00: 35,207 -> 00: 00: 38,664";
console.log(string.replace(/: (?=\d+)/g, ':'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser and the extra explanation regarding `(?=\d+)`. As im very noob with `RegEx`. This helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```js
const test = "00: 00: 35,207 -> 00: 00: 38,664";
console.log(test.replace(/\s*(:|,)\s*/g, "$1"));
```

The regex is simply replacing `:` or `,` surrounded by whitespace with that character.